# Razor Pages Web App (.Net core 2.1) - How to Handle Redirection from one Area Page to another Area Page

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I just updated my **Razor Web Pages Application** from .net core 2.0 to .net core 2.1 and reorganized my code to use **Areas**.

My question is

How to redirect from a page

```
Areas/Identity/Account/Register.cshtml
```

to

```
Areas/Admin/ManageUsers/Index.cshmtl
```

Earlier in .net core 2.0 i was simply using `RedirectToPage("/ManageUsers/Index")` because all my code was under default `Pages` directory.

NOTE: I am not using any routes in `startup.cs`.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Just found the solution.

**Option 1:**.

In `Areas/Identity/Account/Register.cshtml`, use the following url in OnPostAsync()

```
string url = Url.Page("/ManageUsers/Index", new { area = "Admin" });
LocalRedirect(url);
```

**Option 2:** Making use of returnUrl.

While clicking "Register User" link within `Areas/Admin/ManageUsers/Index.cshtml`  send `asp-route-returnUrl` to the "/Account/Register" Page. See below.

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/ManageUsers/Index", new { area = "Administration" })">Register New User</a>
LocalRedirect(url);
```

**Option 2** seems to be more flexible & appropriate.

This was how we can redirect from One **Area** page to another **Area** page.